# Integrate YuiCompressor into TFS build

Tags: yui, minify, tfsbuild

I Already deploy my website using TFS Build template, now i want to add css and js minify and compression using yuicompressor port for .net, i have follow all instruction at [Yui compressor site in Codeplex](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Studio%20Post-build%20Event%20example&ProjectName=yuicompressor) but i have no results. I need some example or any other probed way to use yuicompressor in TFS build proccess.
this is the portion of configuration related with yui-compressor that i have append to my project file

```
<UsingTask
        TaskName="CompressorTask"
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\YUICompressor.NET-MsBuild-Task.1.7.0.0\lib\net35\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceLocation>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</SourceLocation>
    <CssOutputFile>$(SourceLocation)\Content\sylessheetfinal.css</CssOutputFile>
    <JavaScriptOutputFile>$(SourceLocation)\Scripts\javascriptfinal.js</JavaScriptOutputFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="MyTaskTarget">
    <ItemGroup>        
      <!-- All the files. They will be handled (I assume) in alphabetically. -->          
      <CssFiles Include="$(SourceLocation)\Content\*.css" />
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="$(SourceLocation)\Scripts\*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <CompressorTask
        CssFiles="@(CssFiles)"
        DeleteCssFiles="false"
        CssOutputFile="$(CssOutputFile)"
        CssCompressionType="YuiStockCompression"
        JavaScriptCompressionType="YuiStockCompression"
        JavaScriptFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)"
        ObfuscateJavaScript="True"
        PreserveAllSemicolons="False"
        DisableOptimizations="Nope"
        EncodingType="Default"
        DeleteJavaScriptFiles="false"
        LineBreakPosition="-1"
        JavaScriptOutputFile="$(JavaScriptOutputFile)"
        LoggingType="ALittleBit"
        ThreadCulture="en-au"
        IsEvalIgnored="false"/>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Team Build on a Team Foundation Server? The instructions on that web site are for local developer's machine as they mention invoking msbuild.exe on the command-line in post-build event. 
Note that the project file (i.e. csproj) is using msbuild xml syntax so having msbuild.exe in post-build is excessive even for local developer's build - so what you may need to do is to copy parts of their msbuild.xml in your project file, if you are using web application project

Comment: I have try this option too with no result, i get no errors on compile but it not work anyway, will be useful if i can get some logs of yui-compressor task